# Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I'm having this error in Joomla for some reason:

> Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()

[image: image of error]

I see other posts with this error, but I suppose they are using the Joomla app or installed on local files.  In my class exercise, it is obligatory to use the web implementation of Joomla so I don't know how to apply the advice in other answers or if they even work.

Continuing with my case, I can't do anything. I can't enter the website, log out, see the administrator, edit my account, etc.

I am using Joomla 3.1.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, cent3fs9.  I have edited your question to try to improve the English.  If I have damaged any part of your question, please [edit] the question and make appropriate changes. Since you are new here, please take our [tour] and read [ask].  I don't know that volunteers have enough information to help yet.  If there are more clues about how you set up your Joomla site, please edit them into your question body.  Other contributes may ask for more specific details before they are able to answer.

Comment: Please switch error repoting to `development` in your Global Configuration, so that you know which file/line is triggering the error

Answer (score 0):

Your Joomla version is **3.1**. Method `isSite()` is found here:
*libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php* line 733 since **joomla 3.2** and is marked as deprecated.

```
/**
 * Is site interface?
 *
 * @return  boolean  True if this application is site.
 *
 * @since       3.2
 * @deprecated  4.0 Use isClient('site') instead.
 */
public function isSite()
{}
```

May be you're using an extension that is too new for your Joomla version.